# VBScript NOOB Copying File Folders

Tags: file-io, vbscript

based off of what Microsoft tells me here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbfwysex(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbfwysex%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

this script should work

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
    FileSystemObject.CopyFolder "C:\Testing\Test\", "C:\Testing\Test" & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub
```

while playing around, I did receive some errors, which tells me the script is running.  however, this runs w/o error, yet it just doesnt work.  maybe its the date concatenation, so i comment out and just rename the folder to Tests (plural), it too runs w/o error yet doesnt do what it is supposed to.  I've even moved the folder out of c:\Testing to the root of c, nope.  sorry, this is noob but I dont get it.

Comment: "I did receive some errors, which tells me the script is running. however, this runs w/o error" -- make up your mind, is it producing an error or not?

Comment: ok, this exact script does not produce an error.  but a slight variation of it does, such as adding Dim testing As String  that gives me an expected end of statement error.  but with just this one line, it produces no errors, yet i do not see the copied file folder

Comment: Are you creating the "FileSystemObject" object?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as `VBScript`? Because `As String` (which you mentioned in your comment) and the `Format()` function are not available in VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can't use `Format()`. Also, if you don't need the time, use `Date` instead of `Now`. Here's a VBScript alternative.

```
' Global scope...
Dim FileSystemObject

' Somewhere along the way...
Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Your function...
Sub Copy_Folder()

    Dim strDate
    strDate = Year(Date) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(Date), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Date), 2)

    FileSystemObject.CopyFolder "C:\Testing\Test\", "C:\Testing\Test" & "_" & strDate

End Sub
```

Finally, your code above *should* have returned an error. Make sure you're not using `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code. It's almost never a good idea, especially for beginners or when debugging.